# CakePHP requiring a database table

Tags: cakephp

I intended to create a controller that handles a contact page. I created the controller ContactsController. The problem is that it is asking for a table with the same name:

> Missing Database Table
>
> Error: Database table
>   username_contacts for model Contact
>   was not found.
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this
>   error message, create
>   app/views/errors/missing_table.ctp

Do I really need to create a table with no data for this?

This is my controller code:

```
<?php
class ContactsController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Contacts';


    function index($id = null)
    {
        $this->set('page', ClassRegistry::init('Page')->findByShortname($id));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $name = 'Contacts';
var $uses = array();
```

not to be that guy, but this is documented well.
http://book.cakephp.org

Answer (score 2):

You might want to create the model anyway as you'll almost certainly find you need to do some database type stuff. It doesn't need to use a db_table:

```
class ModelWithoutTable extends AppModel
{
    var $useTable = false;
}
```

Think "fat model - thin controller"